# LWJGL/OpenGL -- Not drawing basic quad

Tags: lwjgl, opengl-4

I have looked everywhere, and I can't seem to get OpenGL to draw a simple quad.
The window shows up fine with the correct color background, but OpenGL just won't draw the box. 
I am using OpenGL 4.4.0 - Build 20.19.15.4463
The window size is 1920x1080

This is the code I currently have:

in Main.java:

```
public void init(){
    if(glfwInit() != true){
        System.err.println("GLFW failed to initialize");
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    //TODO change name.
    window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "GameName", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL){
        System.err.println("Window failed to be created");
    }

    GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, 100, 100);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwShowWindow(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


    //set up projection matrix; allows us to draw.
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);


    testBox = new EntityBox(3, Color.RED);//just to test right now

    System.out.println("OpenGL: "+ glGetString(GL_VERSION));

}
public void update(){
    glfwPollEvents();

}
public void render(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    testBox.draw();
}
```

in EntityBox:

```
public void draw(){
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(0,0);
        glVertex2f(0,100);
        glVertex2f(100,0);
        glVertex2f(100,100);
    glEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:
glClear needs to be

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

don't know why, because i was tole depth_buffer is used if you want 3d.
and

```
glfwSwapBuffers(window);
```

needs to be called after drawing.